# iOS 5 :Asynchronous rettrieval of pList - received data is always 0 bytes

Tags: asynchronous, ios5, nsurlconnection

Hi Im trying to get a property List stored on a server onto my device using the NSURLConnection Delegate methods.

I saw some tutorials in the Jeff LaMarche's iOS 3 book and basically Im trying to implement those methods.

These are the implementation methods

But I always keep getting :"Received 0 bytes of data" I dont understand it:

```
#pragma -NSURLCOnnection Delegate Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"%s %s %d", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}
//==============================================================================
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
   [receivedData appendData:data];
   NSLog(@"%s %s %d", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__); 
    if(!self.receivedData)
    {
        NSLog(@"Received Data was nil");
    }
}
//==============================================================================
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                           message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Connection Failed! Error: %@ ,(URL:%@)", [error localizedDescription] ,[[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]]
                           delegate:self 
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert1 show];


    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",[error localizedDescription],[[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
    NSLog(@"%s %s %d", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"%s %s %d", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.receivedData length]);
    //Now take the data and convert it into a propertylist
    NSData *plistData = self.receivedData;
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSString *error;
    id pList = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData
                                                mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                          format:&format
                                                errorDescription:&error];


    if(!pList)
    {
        NSLog(@"There was an error converting data received into a propertyList");
        NSLog(error);
    }

    self.receivedData = nil;
    NSLog(@"%s %s %d", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
}

-(void)retrieveFileFromServerAsynchronously
{
    NSLog(@"%s %s %d", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    if(![self getURLToGetFileFrom])
    {    
        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                              message:@"InvalidPath" 
                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert1 show];
    }

    if(![self getFileName])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                               message:@"Invalid FileName" 
                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert2 show];


    }


    NSLog(@"%s %s %d", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

    NSMutableString *urlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[self getURLToGetFileFrom]];

    [urlString appendString:[self getFileName]];
    NSLog((@"Fetching file from URL %@", urlString));

    NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                          timeoutInterval:60.00 ];

    NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];


    if(con)
    {
        NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init ];
        self.receivedData = data;
        if(!self.receivedData)
            NSLog(@"Received Data was nil");
        NSLog(@"%s %s %d", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%s %s %d", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                              message:@"Couldn't connect to remote server" 
                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}
```

Im getting the above output on the console. Can someone give me any idea where to start fixing this?

fileFetcher.m -[fileFetcher connection:didReceiveResponse:] 183
fileFetcher.m -[fileFetcher connection:didReceiveData:] 190
Received Data was nil
fileFetcher.m -[fileFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] 215
Succeeded! Received 0 bytes of data
There was an error converting data received into a propertyList
stream had too few bytes
fileFetcher.m -[fileFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] 236

Thanks a lot.

Comment: receivedData isn't weak, is it?

Comment: Yes it was weak. Holy **** that WAS the problem then. Wow, its weird, I spent about 1 day on debugging this stuff!! These changes in iOS 5 are driving me nuts!!

Thanks  a lot. You can "answer" my question so I can accept accept your answer.

Comment: Added an answer with a little more detail why this would happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest reason receivedData would be nil after being set in the retrieveFileFromServerAsynchronously is if it's being nulled out for being a weak reference.

When you alloc/init the local "data" variable, you create a strong reference, but you then assign it to a zeroing weak reference and return from the method, causing "data" to go out of scope, losing the only strong reference and causing the weak reference receivedData to be nulled out.